# Reactjs updating state from parent came from child without re-rendering the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am a beginner at using reactjs. Now I have a situation of optimizing my reactjs project. I have an Autocomplete component from material-ui which I made separated from my parent component so that any key changes from my auto-complete may not cause re-render my whole parent component. Now my problem is about updating my state from my child component to the parent component because it re-renders including my parent component. Any tips on how may I avoid re-rendering my parent component? Am I aiming for an impossible scenario? Suggestions/Answers are appreciated for a beginner like me on how may I optimize passing/updating my state from child to parent.

I know that the `setState` function causes re-rendering. In my Parent component, how can I avoid using `setState` inside the `SearchTrainingData` function so that it may not re-render on the other hand it updates my state? My Parent Component has the following function:

```
import SearchTraining from '../components/training/SearchTraining';

const Parent = () => {
    const SearchTrainingData = (index) => { 
    // console.log(index);   
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      trainingTitle: index,
    }));
  };   
  
  return (
      <>
        <SearchTraining SearchTrainingData={SearchTrainingData} />
      </>
  )
  
}
```

Here is my child component which uses the `props.SearchTrainingData` to pass my updated state from my child to parent component?

```
const SearchTraining = (props) => {

    const onChangeAutoComplete = (key, val) => {
        console.log(key);
        props.SearchTrainingData(val);        
      };

    return (
        <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        disabled={
        selectedRecord && selectedRecord.conducted_training.locked
        }
        options={!selectedRecord ? state.trainingConductList : []}
        getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        option.title && option.title.title
            ? option.title.title
            : state.trainingTitle
        }
        getOptionSelected={(o, v) => o.id === v.id}
        value={state.training}
        renderOption={(option) => (
        <ListItemText
            primary={
            <>
                <Box>
                <Typography align="right">
                    <Button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setState((prev) => ({
                        ...prev,
                        newTrainingConduct: true,
                        isClicked: true,
                        }));
                    }}
                    >
                    Not what you&apos;re looking for?
                    </Button>
                </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Typography variant="body1" component="p">
                {option.title.title}
                </Typography>
            </>
            }
            secondary={
            <>
                <Box mt={1} mb={1}>
                <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    component="p"
                    color="textSecondary"
                >
                    CONDUCTED BY:
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    variant="overline"
                    component="p"
                    color="textPrimary"
                >
                    {option.conducted_by.name}
                </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box mt={1}>
                <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    component="p"
                >
                    {option.from_date} - {option.to_date}
                </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box mt={1} mb={1}>
                <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    component="p"
                >
                    Duration (hours): {option.total_hours}{' '}
                    {option.total_hours <= 1 ? ' hour' : ' hours'}
                </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Divider />
            </>
            }
        />
        )}
        onChange={(e, i) => {
        e.persist();
        if (i) {            
            onChangeAutoComplete('training', i);
        }
        }}
        />
    )
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ref instead of state. With using refs you can avoid re-rendering the components after certain values are updated.

In parent component:

```
const ref=useRef(null)
const changeRef=(value)=>{ ref.current=value }
```

Now instead of passing the state and setState to Child, you pass ref and change Ref. (or you can put changeRef inside SearchTrainingData, that's up to you)

In  Child component:

```
const onChangeAutoComplete = (key, val) => {
    console.log(key);
    props.changeRef(val);        
  };
```

In Autocompelete :

```
        value={props.ref.current}
```

Comment: Great for recommending this useRef